# Finite (schema) axiomatizability of representable cylindric algebras

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

If we know that the class of all representable cylindric algebras of dimension $\alpha$ (for any ordinal number $\alpha>2$) is NOT finitely (schema) axiomatizable*, then does it (perhaps trivially) follow that the class of all representable cylindric algebras (of any dimension) is NOT finitely (schema) axiomatizable?

*This, to my understanding, has been proven in (Monk 1969).